# Removing an old refrigerator water line tap and patch the pipe

Tags: plumbing

An old unused/capped refrigerator water line developed a pinhole and was leaking water, so I closed its valve.  Now, the valve is slowly dripping.

It's one of those kits where it pierces a water line.  Is there any way to remove the valve from the water pipe and patch the pipe?

[image: Water valve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try tightening the brass nut right above the handle. That should top the leak. Use an adjustable wrench, not pliers or channel locks.
If you remove the valve, you'll have to install a repair sleeve on the pipe and sweat solder it for the best results.

Comment: If it's to be left exposed, the easiest thing to do is put a new saddle valve. Should be sweated though.

Comment: @Mazura That's a good idea.  I'll keep that in mind.  I got the water to stop dripping from the valve by following Jack's suggestion.  The valve is still letting a very small amount of water to the tube... which I'm assuming is reality for this type of valve.  I plan to remove the tube and cap the valve off.